# Is there a way to convert a string into literal code that you can use in Kotlin?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, class, type-conversion

This might be a very silly question, but I am logging the methods that are triggered in my app as strings. When an issue is submitted, I would like to automatically input the text of the strings as parameters for methods. E.g:

For method:

```
fun assignPot(potType: PotType, ball: DomainBall, action: PotAction) {...}
```

I'd like to somehow call method:

```
assignPot(FOUL(2, BLUE(5), SWITCH))
```

From String:

```
"FOUL(2, BLUE(5), SWITCH)"
```

The only workaround I can think of is to split the string and create a when -> then function to get actual classes from strings, but I wondered if there's a more concise way for this.

Comment: You know that Kotlin is compiled language not scripting?

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want to do. You should design your app in a way that prevents users from providing input similar to actual code.
**However**, you can achieve this. Complex parsings like this oftenly use regex-based approaches.

As you said, you should map your string part to class. If your `PotType` is enum, you can do something like

```
val re = Regex("[^A-Za-z\s]")
val reNumbers = Regex("[^0-9\s]")
// get classes
val classNames = originalString.replace(re, "").split(" ")
// get their constructor numerical arguments
val classArgs = originalString.replace(reNumbers, "").split(" ")
```

After that you can implement mapping with `when` expression. You probably will use some collection of `Any` type.
As you see, this sadly leads you to parsing code by code. **Concise** way to solve is to implement your own script compiler/interpreter and use it in your application **:)** That will later lead you to dealing with security breaches and so on.

If you are logging problematic method calls and want to repeat them immediately after issue is submitted, you probably want to programatically save the calls to lambdas and call them when you receive an issue log.